# Font Ligature for text

Tags: customization, visual-studio-code, workspace

I want to use Font Ligatures, I already set it up but I want it for Text also like I have seen some YouTubers have fancy ligatures on their `return` keyword. How do I do that.

Please help me.

Sincerely, A Developer Like You .

Comment: You will need to find a specific font that supports that. Ligatures are a font feature, not some external configuration

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Can I know what fonts are supported

Comment: See Tools>Options>Environment>Fonts and Colors, use any fixed-width font (is best for code). Examples to search for: "Cascadia Code", "Fira Code" or any "developer font"